Nuxt3 with prerender and detach cli
When building via npm run dev for "simple" ssr the process ends after the build is complete and the cli is freed again to be used by the user.
When introducing prerender, i.e. adding a routeRules section in nuxt.config.ts  and running npm run build --prerender, even after the build has finished (✔ You can preview this build using node .output/server/index.mjs) the process is still running and the cli is not available.
Why is this difference? I would expect the cli to be released at the end of the build process, am I missing something? Is this the correct/expected behavior?

after looking at

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#routerules-1
https://nitro.unjs.io/config#routerules

finally found https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/prerendering#crawl-based-pre-rendering

This will build your site, stand up a nuxt instance, and, by
default, prerender the root page / along with any of your site's pages
it links to, any of your site's pages they link to, and so on.

